# Reg expr to get number after string

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
"test/12"
```

The `test/` part is always fairly similar i.e. it could sometimes be `test-ipad/`,`test-iphone/`, etc...

And there will always be a number after the `/`.

What reg exp can I use in grails/groovy to retrieve the number?

Thanks

Comment: Is there always a `/`? Becuase you have not given it in `test-iphone`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
test(-\w+)?\/(\d+)
```

The second matched group will be the number.

Comment: If you change it to `test(?:-\w+)?\/(\d+)` then the first matched group will be the number